# Cannot connect to host encompasshealth.com:443 ssl:default [None]

Tags: python, ssl, python-asyncio, python-3.8, sitemap

**CODE of ERROR**

```
import sys
import logging
from pysitemap import crawler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if '--iocp' in sys.argv:
        from asyncio import events, windows_events
        sys.argv.remove('--iocp')
        logging.info('using iocp')
        el = windows_events.ProactorEventLoop()
        events.set_event_loop(el)
 
    # root_url = sys.argv[1]
    root_url = 'https://encompasshealth.com/concordrehab'
    crawler(root_url, out_file='sitemap.xml')
```

**ERROR**

> has error 'Cannot connect to host encompasshealth.com:443 ssl:default
> [None]'

Comment: From same host, can you connect to the site with any other tool? Right now the site does not seem to respond, so the problem is not in your code. You just need to add logic to trap errors and deal with them depending on how it is appropriate in your use case. You will get problems like that all the time, Internet offers best effort service, not guaranteed service.

Comment: Please check that the site is up in the first place before asking why it fails from Python. I can not even access the given URL in the browser.